# Regex POSIX - How can i find if the start of a line contains a word from a word that appears later in line

Tags: regex, posix

I have a UNIX passwd file and i need to find using egrep if the first 7 characters from GECOS are inside the username. I want to check if the username (jkennedy) contains the word "kennedy" from the GECOS.

I was planning to use back-references but the username is before the gecos so i don't know how to implement it.

For example the passwd file contains this line:

> jkennedy:x:2473:1067:kennedy john:/root:/bin/bash

Comment: What about reading each line in a file, reversing it and checking it against `([^:\n]{7}):(?:[^:\n]*:){3}[^:]*?(\1)[^:]*?$`? I know it's not POSIX, but if you could use another engine, it should work.

Comment: I tried before with reversing the line and checking it against `^.*:.*:(.){7}.*:.*:.*:.*\1` which worked but i don't know how to do it without reversing the line.
(By the way, reversed line became like this: 
`/bin/bash:/root:kennedy john:1067:2473:x:jkennedy`)

Comment: Do you want case sensitivity, or not?

Comment: No, i'm using the flag `-i` in egrep

Comment: What about `^[^:]*([^:]{7})(?:[^:]*:){4}(\1).*`? It's working for me. Are there any other lengths you need to consider, or is it strictly 7?

Comment: It's basically the first 7 characters but it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my original comment, the regex below works for me.

[See it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3XCCoE/1) - note this regex differs slightly as it's more used for display purposes. The regex below is the POSIX version of this and removes non-capture groups and the unneeded capture group around the backreference.

```
^[^:]*([^:]{7})([^:]*:){4}\1.*$
```

- `^` assert position at the start of the line
- `[^:]*` match any character except `:` any number of times
- `([^:]{7})` capture exactly seven of any character except `:`
- `([^:]*:){4}` match the following exactly four times

  - `[^:]*:` match any character except `:` any number of times, followed by `:` literally
- `\1` match the backreference; matches what was previously matched by the first capture gorup
- `.*` match any character (except newline characters) any number of times
- `$` assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: regex101.com doesn't have a POSIX option; you are testing a Perl regular expression. POSIX regular expressions don't have non-capture groups. You have to use regular parentheses and adjust the back reference used. (Also, I don't think there's any need for parentheses around the back reference.)

Comment: @chepner thank you, I've updated my answer with your proposed changes and added a note with the regex101 link

Comment: I already did the required changes before testing because thanks to that i also searched and learned about non-capture groups so i guess it was for the better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do NOT want case sensitivity to foul your matching -

```
declare -l tmpUsr tmpName
while IFS=: read usr x x x name x
do tmpUsr="$usr"; tmpName="$name"
   (( ${#name} )) && [[ "$tmpUsr" =~ ${tmpName:0:7} ]] &&
      printf "$usr ($name<${tmpName:0:7}>)\n"
done</etc/passwd
```

Comment: But you specify "using `egrep`". I'll think some more on it.